# When I download my HTML document with HtmlConverter, I cannot prevent the images to appear cut off, any ideas?

Tags: java, itext

[cropped image with htmlConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGLhr.png)

Comment: I´m using this versions com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.2.2 and com.itextpdf:html2pdf:4.0.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.